# Is good idea to implement ProxySQL in production with Docker?

Tags: mysql, high-availability, docker, proxysql

The idea is to have solution with ProxySQL to give high availability solution with docker implementation? But this question maybe not have sense, I am to investigate alternative solution without VIP implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HA implies that something will break.  But if all the pieces are in the same server, it seems like the most likely thing to break is the server -- taking down everything.

For HA to be really effective, you need separate servers geographically separated.

A blend would be to have such separate servers, then have dockers in each.  This could, for example, provide multiple HA systems sharing, say, 3 servers, where each system is split up for HA.

At that point, you should consider Galera (PXC or MariaDB) for its HA capabilities in 3 nodes in different locations.  Each node could be in a docker if desired.